# Library Project does the manifest file merge?

Tags: android

I am thinking of creating a core application library (a library project with all the logic), a free version)and a full version  that use this library.

As I understand some things in the manifest do not merge down like permissions and activities, does the version code merge?  Could I put a single version code in the library to apply to both the free and paid versions?

The second question is, my current application (The one I will turn into an Android library) depends on a library, therefore if I make it a library, as I understand it, you cannot have a library inherit from a library.  How do I get around this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

THIS ANSWER WAS CORRECT FOR EARLIER VERSIONS OF THE ANDROID SDK BUT IS NOW OBSOLETE.
SEE Hayes's ANSWER BELOW FOR MORE UP-TO-DATE INFO.

1. The manifest file for a library project is almost totally not used.  The only part that's necessary is the manifest element with a package attribute.  I believe the rest of the manifest for a library project is ignored.
2. The android tools released in Sept 2010 do support a library project referencing a library project.  The docs state otherwise, but I'm pretty sure they are out-of-date.

Comment: Tried referencing a library that also references another library, and it doesn't work. The classes are not being resolved.

Comment: I have no problem here referencing a library from a library. Maybe you did something wrong?

Comment: Obsolete answer. See @Hayes Haugen answer's two years later.

Answer (score 42):

AndroidManifest.xml merging is supported in version 20 of the ADT tools:

> "Automatic merging of library project manifest files into the including project's manifest. Enable with the manifestmerger.enabled property."

http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview

You will need version 20.0.3 or newer to get it to work within Eclipse.

Release notes for [ADT 21 preview](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/adt-21-preview) has this comment:

> "Fixed manifest merger to properly adapt library classes in the merged manifest."

Not sure what this means but may be worth checking out if you are having merge issues.

Comment: This has been fixed in 20.0.3 (for me at least). Please reconfirm.

Comment: I guess things have moved on since the original answer was accepted. This is now the correct answer as at Oct 2012

Answer (score 0):

Manifests are not merged, but I recall there's an include statement in Android XMLs.

Arbitrary-level library dependence was introduced in a recent version of Android SDK IIRC.

Comment: I have the most recent version of the SDK, does this mean it is ok to have libraries inheriting from libraries (Arbitrary-level library dependence)

Comment: In the documentation is says that "Note that a library project cannot itself reference another library project"

Comment: Just created a library that depends on another library, and built them. Eclipse Ganymede, Android tools v.0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 (probably even not the most recent one).

Comment: What do you mean by "there's an include statement in Android XMLs"? Is there an easy way to include list of activities from AndroidManifest.xml that's in Library Project?

Comment: I was mistaken, it seems. Manifest files don't support include. Sorry.

Comment: No, the include is only for layouts.