# Android: Library Project: Is it possible to start a IntentService from Library Project?

Tags: android

What are the checkpoints in creating an IntentService into Library Project in order to use it in other Android Application Project?

My library project has different package.

For example:

Library Project: com.locationplatform.position

Application Project: mobile.app

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: And what is the problem? Have you tried it? I swear it works. Just register it in the manifest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible to invoke a service in the library project from the application project. The only trouble is that the Manifest files doesn't merge. You will have to add the permissions for the activities, services in the library project manually in the application project manifest. Also don't forget to give the absolute package path for the services in the library project. Check this question too. [Library Project does the manifest file merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457219/library-project-does-the-manifest-file-merge)

Edit. [Setting up Library projects in Android.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)

Comment: cool~ I will accept your answer. Just a follow up, is there any template to start? or links to follow like tutorial?