# How do I edit project.properties if it says it's auto-generated?

Tags: android, adt

I want to put:

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

in my `project.properties` file ([see here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457219/library-project-does-the-manifest-file-merge); from googling it looks like this line is supposed to be added to `project.properties`). However, at the top of my `project.properties` file, it says:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
```

If my `project.properties` file is auto-generated and I'm not supposed to edit it, where do I put my `manifestmerger.enabled=true` statement? I've been looking around but can't find an obvious place where it should go or how to edit `project.properties` such that my edits aren't replaced when the file is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the setting into `ant.properties` file.
The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the

According to `build.xml`:

```
     The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
     'android' tool to add properties to it.
     This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
     Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

     source.dir
         The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
     out.dir
         The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

     For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
     files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

     Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
     be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.
```

And `manifestmerger.enabled` is listed in `tools/ant/build.xml`.

Comment: Really? Interesting... [Google says to put it in project.properties](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Erd2k6EKxCQ&noredirect=1#t=2939s), but I'll try that.

Comment: Does not work. Even tried to edit build.xml to override the property in there, without success.