# Why is "Your location approximate location (network-based)" being added as a permission even though I haven't declared it in the manifest?

Tags: android, location, andengine, android-permissions

I have the following 2 permissions being asked when I install the app

1. Phone calls - read phone status and identity
2. Your location approximate location (network-based)

I am using "Andengine" and "Swarm-connect" as external libraries in the app. Does andengine require these permissions? How are they getting automatically added to the app even though I haven't declared it in the manifest?

Comment: If you're using an application, inside one of your own applications and if the app included requires those permissions, they will have to be included in the controlling App as well, as it controls the Application.

Comment: By application do you mean libraries like andengine or swarm?

Comment: Yes, applications, external libraries, just libraries, other external resources etc. if they require those permissions, then you application should also.

Comment: So if I just import the library and add it to my java build path as something.jar, it will use the permissions defined in the jar files for my app as well, even if I don't specify those permissions in my manifest?

Comment: AndEngine doesn't require either of those permissions - must be the Swarm-connect stuff

Comment: Thanks jmr499485. I just have a clarification. If i import a jar file, those permissions are also imported to my app, even if i dont explictily write them in the manifest?

Comment: No, you have to re-import them in the App, which uses this something.jar, that's for sure !

Comment: Hmm thats the thing. I haven't written these permissions in my manifest, but for some reason its showing up on app install.

Comment: see http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/faq -> that's the cause for your permissions. for the merging problem, look up your .project.properties in eclipse, if manifestmerger.enabled=true is set, that could be the cause of the merge (like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457219/library-project-does-the-manifest-file-merge - i m not sure with this one, that's why it's not an answer, just a comment

Answer (score 2):

as stated in the questions comments, here is the solution:

see http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/faq -> that's the cause for your permissions.

for the merging problem, look up your .project.properties in eclipse, if manifestmerger.enabled=true is set, that could be the cause of the merge (like mentioned here: [Library Project does the manifest file merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457219/library-project-does-the-manifest-file-merge)